# Trying to put my list item with background red when click on my "Delete" link

Tags: jquery

When I click in my "Delete" link I want to put my list item with background red.

Im trying to do this with my code below, but it is not working.

I review code a lot of times and I dont find where the problem is.

Do you see what Im doing wrong here?

This is my html:

```
<div class="posts">
    <ul class="content bannerli">
        <?php
        $read = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM banners");
        $read->execute();

        while ($result = $read->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

             echo '<li  class="li id="'.$result['id'].'">';
                 echo '<div class="info">';
                     echo '<p class="title">'.$result['title'].'</p>';
                     echo '<p class="img">'.$result['img'].'</p>'; 
                     echo '<span>';
                      echo '<a title="Delete" id="'.$result['id'].'" class="delete j_banndelete" href="#">Delete</a>';
                     echo '</span>';
                 echo '</div>';
             echo '</li>';
         }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$('.bannerli').on('click','.j_banndelete',function(){
    var bannerid = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.bannerli li[id="'+ bannerid +'"]').css('background','red');

return false;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allowed to have multiple elements with the same id. Add a prefix to them (`id=li_XXXX`, `id=delete_XXXX`, etc.), or use the hierarchy (e.g. `$(this).parent().parent().parent().css(...)`)

Comment: Thank you, your solution works. But is very very strange. Because I have other example using my question same method with two elements with id and it works perfectly.

Comment: If you have two elements with the same id, what happens is completely undefined. Some browsers might pick the first one, others the last one, and still others completely ignore it. In any case, it is completely forbidden by the specs.

Comment: Thank you also for your clear and helpful explanation!